# apply a function for each matrix in an array

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, apply

I have an array with 3 matrices in it. I wish to apply the function "norm" to each matrix individually, resulting in an array with 3 matrices in it.

My function:

```
apply(DS,1, norm, "2")
```

for each matrix:

```
apply(DS[,,1], 1, norm, "2")
```

now I wish to do this for each matrix in the array:

```
for (i in 1:3) apply(DS[,,i], 1, norm, "2") #> this does not work?
```

Is there any way to do this? If I do the first function, it applies it to all 3 matrices, but gives me only one matrix back, not 3?

Comment: Sorry! I am using R :)

Comment: I have figured it out!
apply(DS,c(1,3), norm, "2")
This does it for every row and every matrix :)

Comment: You can post that as an answer.